# How to avoid more if-else statement in following trigger

Tags: trigger

Requirement:

scenarios:

I have object Inquiry. It contains 3 accounts. they are primary Inquiry account,secondary Inquiry Account and third inquiry Account

In Account level,I have global key account (checkbox) and Global Key Account Responsibility(lookup to user).

Problem:

Email needs to be sent to Global Key Account Responsibility user if Global Key Account is checked for Account

If it is checked on all 3 inquiry Accounts, email should be sent to all 3 Global Key Account Responsibility users

**if same User is specified on Primary, Secondary and Third Inquiry company, only one email should be sent**

**We also need to ensure there is no duplicate email sent**

So I had written trigger for that :

```
public class s360_InquiryUpdateDetails {
 public static void inquiryInformation(List < Opportunity > opList) {
   set < id > primaryAccount = new set < id > ();
   set < id > secondaryAccount = new set < id > ();
   set < id > thirdAccount = new set < id > ();
   map < id, string > primaryOppName = new map < id, string > ();
   map < id, string > secondaryOppName = new map < id, string > ();
   map < id, string > ThirdOppName = new map < id, string > ();

   for (Opportunity op: opList) {
    //Primary Account
    if (op.AccountId != null) {
     primaryAccount.add(op.AccountId);
     primaryOppName.put(op.AccountId, op.Name);
    }
    //secondary
    if (op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c != null) {

     secondaryAccount.add(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c);
     secondaryOppName.put(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c, op.name);
    }
    //Third
    if (op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c != null) {
     thirdAccount.add(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c);
     ThirdOppName.put(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c, op.name);
    }
   } // for loop end
   //system.debug('secondary Account:::'+secondaryAccount);

   map < id, id > primaryAccountMap = new map < id, id > ();
   map < id, string > primaryAccountMap1 = new map < id, string > ();
    map < id, string > primaryAccountUserMap = new map < id, string > ();
   map < id, id > secondaryAccountMap = new map < id, id > ();
   map < id, string > secondaryAccountMap1 = new map < id, string > ();
   map < id, string > secondaryAccountUserMap= new map < id, string > ();
   map < id, id > thirdAccountMap = new map < id, id > ();
   map < id, string > thirdAccountMap1 = new map < id, string > ();
   map < id, string > thirdAccountUserMap= new map < id, string > ();
   for (Account ac: [SELECT id, name, Key_Account__c, Key_Account_Responsibility__c,Key_Account_Responsibility__r.Name from Account where(id in : primaryAccount OR id in : secondaryAccount OR id in : thirdAccount)
     and Key_Account__c = true]) {
    if (primaryAccount.contains(ac.Id)) {
     primaryAccountMap.put(ac.id, ac.Key_Account_Responsibility__c);
     primaryAccountMap1.put(ac.id, ac.name);
     primaryAccountUserMap.put(ac.id,ac.Key_Account_Responsibility__r.Name);
    } 
     else if (secondaryAccount.contains(ac.Id)) {
     secondaryAccountMap.put(ac.id, ac.Key_Account_Responsibility__c);
     secondaryAccountMap1.put(ac.id, ac.name);
     //system.debug('res:::'+ac.Key_Account_Responsibility__r.Name);
     secondaryAccountUserMap.put(ac.id,ac.Key_Account_Responsibility__r.Name);
    } 
    else if (thirdAccount.contains(ac.Id)) {
     thirdAccountMap.put(ac.id, ac.Key_Account_Responsibility__c);
     thirdAccountMap1.put(ac.id, ac.name);
     thirdAccountUserMap.put(ac.id,ac.Key_Account_Responsibility__r.Name);
    }

   }

  // system.debug('primary account'+primaryAccountUserMap);
   system.debug('secondary Account'+secondaryAccountMap);
   List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > mails = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > ();
   for (Opportunity op: opList) {
   //3 are equal
    if (primaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.AccountId)==secondaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c) &&
         secondaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c)==thirdAccountMap.containsKey(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c) ) {

     mails.add(createEmailMessage(primaryAccountMap.get(op.AccountId), primaryAccountMap1.get(op.AccountId), primaryOppName.get(op.AccountId),primaryAccountUserMap.get(op.AccountId)));
     }

     else if (secondaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c)==primaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.AccountId)&& 
     secondaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c)!=thirdAccountMap.containsKey(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c)) {
       mails.add(createEmailMessage(secondaryAccountMap.get(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c), secondaryAccountMap1.get(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c), secondaryOppName.get(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c),secondaryAccountUserMap.get(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c)));
       }////Two are equal
       else if (secondaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c)==thirdAccountMap.containsKey(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c) &&thirdAccountMap.containsKey(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c)!=primaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.AccountId) ) {
        mails.add(createEmailMessage(secondaryAccountMap.get(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c), secondaryAccountMap1.get(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c), secondaryOppName.get(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c),secondaryAccountUserMap.get(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c)));

       }
       else if (thirdAccountMap.containsKey(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c)==primaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.AccountId) && secondaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c)!=thirdAccountMap.containsKey(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c) ) {
       mails.add(createEmailMessage(primaryAccountMap.get(op.AccountId), primaryAccountMap1.get(op.AccountId), primaryOppName.get(op.AccountId),primaryAccountUserMap.get(op.AccountId)));

       }
       //not equal
       else if (primaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.AccountId)!=secondaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c) &&
         primaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.AccountId)!=thirdAccountMap.containsKey(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c) ) {

     mails.add(createEmailMessage(primaryAccountMap.get(op.AccountId), primaryAccountMap1.get(op.AccountId), primaryOppName.get(op.AccountId),primaryAccountUserMap.get(op.AccountId)));
     }//not equal
     else if (secondaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c)!=primaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.AccountId) &&
         secondaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c)!=thirdAccountMap.containsKey(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c) ) {

     mails.add(createEmailMessage(secondaryAccountMap.get(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c), secondaryAccountMap1.get(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c), secondaryOppName.get(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c),secondaryAccountUserMap.get(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c)));
     }//not equal
      else if (thirdAccountMap.containsKey(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c)!=primaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.AccountId) && thirdAccountMap.containsKey(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c)!=secondaryAccountMap.containsKey(op.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c)) {
        mails.add(createEmailMessage(thirdAccountMap.get(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c), thirdAccountMap1.get(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c), ThirdOppName.get(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c),thirdAccountUserMap.get(op.Third_Inquiring_Company__c)));

       }
      }

      Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
     }
     private static Messaging.SingleEmailMessage createEmailMessage(String userId, string name, string OppName,string Uname) {
     //system.debug('userid:'+userid+'name::'+name+'OppName'+OppName+'name:'+Uname);
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
       EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [Select Id, Name, HtmlValue, Body, Subject from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'Global_Key_Account_Update'];
       String subject = emailTemplate.Subject;
       subject = subject.replace('{!Opportunity.Name}',OppName);
       subject = subject.replace('{!Account.Name}',name);
       String htmlBody = emailTemplate.HtmlValue;
      // htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Account.Key_Account_Responsibility__c}',userId);
       //htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Opportunity.Name}',OppName);
      // mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);   
       String plainBody = emailTemplate.Body;
       plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!Account.Key_Account_Responsibility__c}',Uname);
       plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!Opportunity.Name}',OppName);
       mail.setPlainTextBody(plainBody);           
       mail.setTreatBodiesAsTemplate(True);
       mail.setTargetObjectId(userId);
       mail.saveAsActivity = false;
       //mail.setSenderDisplayName('Test Mail');
       mail.setSubject(subject);
       //String body = 'Test Mail';
        return mail;
     }

    }
```

Code is working fine,but I need a help how to avoid more if-else statements.

suppose: consider a,b and c are users

```
   a=b=c----->  I have to send only one mail [Users are same]
   a=b ----> I have to one mail for user[a and b]  and I have send separate mail for c
```

etc...

In this code I'am getting more if else statement.How to make it very simple.How to make this code simple

Comment: I can suggest you to use retainAll method, to get common ids of all 3 maps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've put way more effort into this than you need to. Also, there is a query inside a for loop which is completely against best practices.

I hope this makes enough sense, I did my best to understand what your code was trying to do but to be perfectly honest your code is very un-readable.

```
public static void inquiryInformation(List<Opportunity> opList) {
    // Use a map for easy de-duping
    Map<String, Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages = new Map<String, Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [
        Select Id, Name, HtmlValue, Body, Subject 
        from EmailTemplate 
        where DeveloperName = 'Global_Key_Account_Update'
    ];

    // You can get almost everything you need with a single query off opp
    // Make sure you include all fields, I may have missed some
    List<Opportunity> oppsWithrequiredInfo = [
        SELECT AccountId, Secondary_Inquiring_Company__c, Third_Inquiring_Company__c,
            Account.Key_Account_Responsibility__c, Secondary_Inquiring_Company__r.Key_Account_Responsibility__c,
            Third_Inquiring_Company__r.Key_Account_Responsibility__c, Account.Key_Account_Responsibility__r.Email,
            Secondary_Inquiring_Company__r.Key_Account_Responsibility__r.Email,
            Third_Inquiring_Company__r.Key_Account_Responsibility__r.Email, Account.Global_Key_Account__c,
            Secondary_Inquiring_Company__r.Global_Key_Account__c, Third_Inquiring_Company__r.Global_Key_Account__c
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE Id IN :opList
    ];

    // Now that I have opps and each opp has a reference to all the required info
    // I can start evaluating the opps
    for (Opportunity opp : oppsWithrequiredInfo) {
        if (opp.AccountId != null && opp.Account.Global_Key_Account__c) {
            messages.put(
                opp.Account.Key_Account_Responsibility__r.Email, // Use email as key for de-duping
                createEmailMessage(
                    opp.Id, 
                    opp.AccountId, 
                    emailTemplate.Id,
                    opp.Account.Key_Account_Responsibility__r.Email
                )
            )
        }

        if (
            !messages.containsKey(opp.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__r.Key_Account_Responsibility__r.Email) &&
            opp.Secondary_Inquiring_Company__r.Global_Key_Account__c
        ) {
            // Create second message
        }

        // repeat third time
    }
}

public static Messaging.SingleEmailMessage createEmailMessage(Id oppId, Id accountId, Id templateId, String recipientAddress) {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage result = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    result.setTartObjectId(oppId);
    result.setWhatId(accountId);
    result.setTemplateId(templateId);
    result.setToAddresses(new List<String>{recipientAddress});

    return result;
}
```

### Cliff notes

- Move your query for the email template out of the create message method to reduce query count, pass in template ID in each call
- Use a Map to de-dup. If you set the key to the email address, you'll never have more than 1 email per address so no dups will go out
- Make sure this is in your after trigger
- Query for all the info you need in 1 query at the opp level, again reduces query count and code complexity
- Instead of setting the user as the target, set the opp as the target and the account as the "whatId". This means you don't need to manually parse the email template as it will automatically fill in the data. You can set the recipient via the `setToAddresses(List<String>)` method
- You said that you had a field called `global key account (checkbox)` but I didn't see this anywhere in your code. I added it in to show how it should look.

### Disclaimer:

While there are some things in the sample I provided that even I would probably change, I'm trying to simplify things for clarity.

### Update

Thinking about it, **if you have account specific information in your email template you probably do want duplicate emails** to go out as if the user is a "key responsibility" on more than 1 account, they will only get 1 email for the first account identified. The emails for subsequent accounts will never be sent and they will have no way to know that the email relates to these other accounts.

Comment: The logic for the key_account__c field is in my if statement, I didn't know what you called the field so I called it "gobal key account". To prevent duplicates you do need that map as it prevents you from sending an email to the same user more than once. Your query is in your `createEmailMessage` since you call this method in a for loop and the method has a query, you have a query in a for loop. If you want to send duplicate emails then yes, you would get rid of the map and use a list instead.

Comment: Also, I can't hold discussions in the comments, I looked at your profile and I know you have done a fair bit of development, you'll have to be able to read, understand, and apply the sample, I cannot do it all for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79423/discussion-between-annappa-ph-and-gnerb).

Comment: @gNerb Awesome answer. \m/